# Allow access to tag wikis from the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

On the website I often click on a tag in a question to read up on more questions about that tag and sometimes the tag wiki.

Currently, clicking a tag in the Android app searches for that tag, but does not provide access to the wiki.

Please provide somewhere to access the wiki summary / more info (full wiki) via the app.

Comment: This is not a dupe as.it requests the tag wikis.

Comment: This feature would also be appreciated on iOS